# How do I append an item from an array that was made using a struct?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift4

I've got a table in ios and I want the selected items from one array to append to another, but when I try I get the error `Cannot subscript a value of type '[VintageThings]' with an index of type 'IndexPath'`

Here's my code that's giving me the error, I've tried looking up how to do this, but all the answers seem to relate to single layer arrays like `array = ["dog","cat"]` etc. Please help me figure this out.

```
var selected: [VintageThings] = []

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt IndexPath: IndexPath) {
   selected.append(newArray[indexPath])
}
```

**EDIT**

How can I get the `selected` array to lock in items from multiple scenes and be usable on a later scene? Do I have to set up the array in an external swift file? I can't tell if items are saving to it or not.

Comment: `selected.append(newArray[indexPath.row])`?

Comment: The first character of the argument is 'IndexPath', not 'indexPath', so, selected.append(newArray[IndexPath.row])

Comment: Ah, of course. thank you! How do I make it so that if I deselect it, it gets removed from the array please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IndexPath consists of two indexes. What you want is `indexPath.row`.
That's because a TableView can also be divided into sections. And if the user taps an item in a given section, you'd want to know which one. That's why IndexPath has a second index `indexPath.section`.

To remove it again from the array you have to use the same method (kind of a toggling-behaviour)

```
let element = newArray[indexPath.row];
if selected.contains(element) {
   selected = selected.filter {$0 = element}
} else {
   selected.append(element)
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! How do I make it so that if I deselect it, it gets removed from the array please?

Comment: What do you mean by deselect?

Comment: Like in a cart type array, when I tap on the item it goes into the array, is there a function to remove it please?

Comment: Well you can tap it again to remove it. This would require you to mark the selected TableViewCell somehow.

Answer (score 0):

update it to indexPath.row to make it working. Updated code here

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    selected.append(newArray[indexPath.row])
}
```

it will do.

**EDIT**

To delete the object from the array, you can first check if the object is existing in the selected. if it is then check for the index of the object and remove the object from it. This is how it can be done.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let selectedObj = newArray[indexPath.row]
    if selected.contains(selectedObj) {
        if let indexOfSelectedObject = selected.index(of: selectedObj) {
            selected.remove(at: indexOfSelectedObject)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Bhavin! How do I make it so that if I deselect it, it gets removed from the array please?